# Inserting unicode character with fontspec does not work

Tags: xetex, fontspec, unicode

I am using XeLaTeX and `fontspec` and trying to insert a Turkish Lira symbol ₺ into my document. Minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newfontfamily\djvuserif{DejaVu Serif}
\newcommand{\Lira}[0]{{\djvuserif ₺}\xspace}

\begin{document}
\Lira 2
\end{document}
```

It just outputs ? 2 (with the question mark in the DejaVu font!). How do I do this properly?

Comment: Possibly, the font you are using does not contain that specific glyph (cf. message in the log: `Missing character: There is no ₺ (U+20BA) in font DejaVu Serif/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;!`

Comment: @lacobus1983, no. U+20BA in DejaVu Serif is displayed in the Character Map and it can be typed in Word. Unless XeLaTeX is using a different version of the font from the one in `C:\Windows\Fonts` ?

Comment: That message does not appear in my `.log` file, either...

Answer (score 1):

The character is not available in DejaVu Serif.

You can see what fonts on your system have it by using

```
albatross ₺
```

from a command line. Here I use Noto Serif, you choose the one you like the most. But no hope with DejaVu Serif.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newfontfamily\lirafont{Noto Serif}
\newcommand{\Lira}[0]{{\lirafont ₺}\xspace}

\begin{document}
\Lira 2
\end{document}
```

[image]

To be honest, I'd not use `\xspace`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newfontfamily\lirafont{Noto Serif}
\newcommand{\Lira}{{\lirafont ₺}}
\newcommand{\TL}[1]{\Lira~#1}

\begin{document}

\Lira

\TL{2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what to say... Character Map clearly displays it as part of the font: https://imgur.com/JbVUUnw

Comment: @noxewa Never trust Character Map. It fills in missing glyphs with font substitution.

Comment: DejaVu Serif also appears in the output of `albatross ₺`

Comment: @noxewa I checked and the DejaVu Serif font distributed with TeX Live doesn't have the character.

Comment: however, I have the latest version 2.37 of DejaVu Serif installed on Windows, which does.

Comment: Does XeLaTeX not know about Windows fonts?

Comment: further, replacing it with `Noto Serif` (also installed) gives the same output, but with ? in Noto Serif!

Comment: @noxewa If you're able to compile from the command line, `xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -v" <filename>` will show on the console all the fonts used.

Comment: It contains `<AGL:texglyphlist.txt><AGL:pdfglyphlist.txt><AGL:glyphlist.txt>[1<C:/WINDOWS/fonts/DejaVuSerif.ttf@9.96pt<NATIVE-FONTMAP:C:/WINDOWS/fonts/DejaVuSerif.ttf/0/H/65536/0/0>(CID:DejaVuSerif)`


`pdf_font>> Type0 font "C:/WINDOWS/fonts/DejaVuSerif.ttf" cmap_id=<Identity-H,0> font_id=<C:/WINDOWS/fonts/DejaVuSerif.ttf/0/H/65536/0/0,1>.`